# What is Oracle ADF?

Tags: soa, oracle-adf

What is Oracle ADF?

On the Internet I found the following definition:

> ADF integrates a mix of subframeworks to provide the key functions for
>   object-relational mapping and other forms of service access, data
>   bindings, and user interface, along with the functional glue to hold
>   it all together.  ADF stands for 'Applications Development Framework'
>   and it's developed by Oracle. ADF is a framework and it'll help you
>   build your applications easily as many of the redundant things that we
>   do while we develop our applications are taken care by the framework.

But I still have a couple of questions with respect to understanding ADF:

1. ADF is an extension to the [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) Framework, and can things that can be done using ADF (including SOA Development) be done by normal Java EE programming? (Please correct me if I am wrong.)
2. Is it mandatory to learn ADF for doing [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) applications?

Comment: I've no idea what ADF is, but I can confidently say that the answer to #2 is "no."

Answer (score 23):

It is a web development framework based on [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces). But heavier!!

If you plan doing web development with this, be warned that this framework is not very flexible. It feels like developing web software as in the 1999 with Visual Studio!!

You build everything in the Oracle IDE JDeveloper (incuding UI!) drag and dropping UI widget already made...  If you can live with the default look and feel and do not want to include popular JavaScript libraries (jQUery) you should be fine. For example, building intranet applications could be OK. But if you want to do a public web application (Internet) I would not recommend this framework!

Comment: Hello, fellow victim of ADF :). Our employer actually made us to build a huge application on ADF, but with custom look! We manage to build and extend ADF components to provide custom look & feel. But it IS a hard thing to do due to low extensibility and a lack of documentation.

Comment: Hehe, i was not actually involved in the dev.  But i was related to people who were responsible to decide if ADF was ok or not.  finally, they decided to kick ADF out and use Spring/Spring MVC + probably AngularJS for the client side.

Comment: not true - you can add query and JS libraries locally or via shared lib. Also with use of Skins (custom CSS) you can achieve high control over L&F. Depdends on envelopment and site needs. It is a *fwk* designed for transactional db-data based apps. Oracle is building their entire new line of apps on it. Hmmm. these comments about low extensibility and customization would indicate to me that one was not properly trained to use the fwk. The fwk has high extensibility in ADF BC (ORM) and full JSF support of managed beans, phase override, etc. Spring is *not* JEE.Comparison is skewed.

Comment: @dragn I'm dragged into ADF by a customer as well. Could you point me to some resources that explain how to extend existing components? thx

Comment: @mac actually, there is none. But I plan to share my experience in this area, check out my blog: http://customize-adf.blogspot.com/. There is no guide about extending components yet but I'll write one soon, I hope...

Comment: No, Extending components is not supported. But, you can create Declarative Components based on grouping together other, existing comps. So while not "extension" - it may still fit your needs. This may help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_40/jdtut_11r2_40.html. Also, IMHO composition is better approach than inheritance, usually.

Comment: I agree, ADF is the worst thing ever

Comment: @Joe "Hmmm. these comments about low extensibility and customization would indicate to me that one was not properly trained to use the fwk" There was a team of Oracle experts trying to adapt the fwk to do what the client needed.  They failed while the other team succeed with standard fwk (bootstrap,Jquery,SpringMVC)

Comment: Oracle should stick to database only and stop putting it nose in things they dont understand

Answer (score 12):

ADF is actually 4 "parts":

ADF Business Components is a declarative, meta-data based object relational mapping solution. It provides robust database read/write/update capabilities without the developer having to use Java (hence declarative) though the framework scan be extended with Java to add custom behavior.

ADF Model is a binding layer to bind the UI (ADF Faces based on JSF) without tight coupling UI components to the back end data model.

ADFController implements task flows, an advance on JSF page flows that allow you to break your application up into reusable sets of pages, called task flows, declarative transaction management.

ADF Faces is based on JSF and built on top of [Trinidad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyFaces_Trinidad), an open source JSF framework.

Yes, you can do almost everything ADF provides (not ADF C) in custom Java EE code. But it's a *framework* - it handles a lot of the repetitive, predictable, redundant code. Also, one can argue that once learned, you can be more productive in ADF than hand coding Java EE applications.

Answer (score 9):

Oracle adf allows you to develop mvc applications that can support enterprise needs mainly.
There are few specific things that you must consider here:

- **entity objects**

These are the core elements of database interaction. They correspond with model layer and business services.
I.e.business logic is implemented here.

- **view objects**

These are the elements that are considered as display elements.
View objects can be updatable or read only.

Updatable view objects are derived from entity objects as any changes in the view objects will reflect in entity object and then reflect in database.

Read only view objects can be developed using standard SQL queries.

- **application module**

These are the core parts of any adf application as they include the view objects those need to be displayed.
Any view that needs to be displayed must be added to application module.

It can also be used for testing the business services as business services need to be validated for correct results before attaching them in the view part.

**SOA (Service oriented architecture)**

This helps you to develop web services using BPEL language and java .
These web services contain business processes which can be used in adf application which further describe any enterprise application.

**Pros:**

- you can develop enterprise applications really fast as all the operations on the database tables are provided to you in data models itself.
- rich set of UI components which can interact in various ways.eg. panel splitter, panel tabbed, decorative box etc.
- web services can be consumed within adf easily.
- it makes the development faster.

**Cons :**

- heavier compared to other alternatives.
- cannot use popular JavaScript libraries like jQuery, Ajax etc.
- UI components look too old compared to latest frameworks like Bootstrap,jQuery etc.

Answer (score 5):

ADF just makes development easier.

1. Yes, you can still develop what you need using the regular Java EE framework
2. It is not mandatory but it might make your life easier and your development time shorter

Please read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html

There's also an [ADF overview video](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/ADF112/ADF112.html) which may help you understand this technology better.

Comment: One comment: ADF makes application development easier IF you have an Oracle technologies stack you need to tie together. If you don't using any Oracle products already you better choose another framework.

Comment: i disgree. ADF works OOTB against any std. jdbc-comliant db and ADF faces is not dependent on oracle stack. It provides complete end to end solution in one integrated fwk w/o having to "bolt"or glue pieces together. What other fwk, OOTB has this level of integration. Now, if one *is* using the oracle FMW stack , then yes, there ar many nice integrations that ADF provides, but i think it is not accurate to say it makes dev. easier [only] IF you have oracle. I can achieve the same level of productivity against an MS or DB2 db.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle ADF (framework) + Oracle Jdeveloper(IDE) make web application very easy and in rapid way.
1.Oracle ADF is a framework on top of JEE stack.
2.it's not required.but if you want to work with oracle SOA suite yes it's required

Answer (score 2):

You can think of ADF as an enhancement to standard Java EE. It has enhancements to multiple layers including data access, business logic and user interface.

SOA is more like a concept and you can implement it with or without ADF.

Comment: GNOME has ADF too... so that term is not just belong to Oracle. Say Oracle ADF

Answer (score 1):

For your query on Oracle ADF,

In layman terms this is what it means...: ADF provides a commercial Java framework for building enterprise applications. It provides visual and declarative approaches to Java EE development. It supports rapid application development based on ready-to-use design patterns, metadata-driven and visual tools.

1) It is possible to develop by normal Java EE programming, but the complexitity is reduced with ADF (Using jDeveloper IDE) as it follows an [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture.

2) No, ADF knowledge is not that mandatory for SOA.

Answer (score 1):

ADF is a framework to create complex enterprise application based on the JSF framework at easier pace. for some coding sample look at my blog below
adf-webcenter.blogspot.com

Comment: Actually GNOME has ADF too... so that term is not just belong to Oracle. Say Oracle ADF

Answer (score 1):

`Oracle ADF` is an end-to-end Java EE framework to make in a simple way the application development using out-of-the-box infrastructure services.

As relevant information:

1. Use MVC pattern.
2. Developed (an easily) integrated with Java EE applications.
3. Some of the `out of the box` functionality doesn't need codification.
4. Similar to a `BPM tool` with `TaskFlows`

And about your questions:

1. ADF is an extension to the Java EE Framework, and can things that can be done using ADF (including SOA Development) be done by normal Java EE programming? **Yes, you're right, also you can work with `JavaEE 7` and `JavaEE 6`.**

Is it mandatory to learn ADF for doing SOA applications? **A user action or other activity in an Oracle ADF web application needs to invoke a SOA composite. The invocation is asynchronous and does not require a response. Inside the SOA composite, an Oracle Mediator component can provide routing and transformation, a BPEL component can provide business process orchestration, a human task service can provide workflows, and a decision service can provide complex business rules based decision making.**

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle ADF is a 4th Generation Language. In the sense one can create a full fledged Java Web Application in few seconds.

Everything is drag-drop behavior right from database table to modelling views in the pages.

The strong part of ADF is task flows. With task flows we can actually organize thousands of fragments in a single page/flow.

One no need to be an expert in any technology to build an application using jDeveloper/ADF. That will make any Web Developers work simple and easy.