# Is Oracle ADF always this hard to deploy?

Tags: oracle-adf

I've been working with Oracle PL/SQL and forms ¿for the last 20 years. 
Like 8 years ago oracle people started to say their route map was that every new development should be done in Java with ADF and not in forms. 
5 years ago we had to start a new project so we did it using that technology, because we had the feeling that sooner or later Oracle was going to stop suporting and publishing new versions of forms and reports.
The project was successful, but mantinance, deployment and configuring the developer's PC's is a lot hard and painful.
Starting with the fact that we have to deploy all the application every time we do an small change in any page, comparing with the fact that in forms we just have to deploy the altered form's FMX
And that is not the most unconfortable part, some times we deploy the applications EAR and we do not know why some classes are missing, so we have to compile everything again and deploy again.
In the last month we had to change our old Win 7 PC's for new ones, but I do not know why when I run the ant XML that should generate the EAR it does not find oracle.jbo.server package

Is this developing environmet always so hard and buggy ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I understand this thread below is a bit old... but still a good source to refer it.

[What is Oracle ADF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138686/what-is-oracle-adf)